# How to I match parts of an input to an output

Tags: php, mysql

Okay here is my background. I am attempting to create a page that takes input and displays output. Yea easy right? Well it's a little more complicated than that. First off I'm trying to do this for Chemistry. I'm working with cations and anions. A simply list of the common ones can be found [here](http://www.chemteam.info/Nomenclature/HO1-Anion-Cation-List.pdf).

My goal is to take the input of a user and based on that input give them the appropriate balanced equation and name. The process for doing that can be found [here](http://www.bowvalleycollege.ca/Documents/Learning%20Resource%20Services/Library%20Learning%20Commons/E-Resources/Study%20guides%202/chemistry%20rules_for_naming.pdf).

The first thing I need to do is parse the information in order to find what element it is and what charge it has. I believe the best way to do this would be to create an array with the chemical symbol, name, and charge.

After determining what the cation and anion is I will then do the "criss-cross" method to find the balanced charge. From there I need to look up what the elemental name is for each ion. After doing this I find the name that matches up with the formula then I add how many of each element would come before the name.

My first problem comes when I attempt to combine all this information together into one string. How do I add these three strings together.

My second problem comes in part from the parsing and in part from the array. When there are more complex ions for two reasons first. The way I was parsing the information was by capital letters. This created quite the little problem when people used these bigger ions because then I have to deal with a sizable number of these. Or when they they attempt to represent multiple of the same compound. IE they write something like this Mg(ClO/4)/2 (I am using forward slashes to represent number of elements of that type). I need to make sure that I have two of the ClO/4. How would you find I first parse this correctly to acquire the elements? The how would I make sure I kept straight who has how many of what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not be a simple application. You will need to start with a comprehensive list of elements, ions, molecules, etc as well as their properties and variations of their names. After that you'll have to use a variety of [string functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) to match the user input to something in that data.

As for the output, you can use HTML/CSS functions for sub/superscript like toninoj mentioned, of for something more complex you'll likely want to look into [LaTeX](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics).

There are probably entire university courses that cover things like this, and commercial software packages that do exactly this.

Comment: I have the list but the thing is I can't figure out which strings I need and how I need to use them, the ones I know won't help me here.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you need is [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function. That is, where you simply want to choose first 2, 3 or whatever letters.
But in cases where you need custom abbreviation form, you will need to provide it in the form of [associative array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), or something like that.

So inside the array you will have `$myarray = ["name"=>"MagnesiumWhatever", "abbreviation"=>"Mg24xy"]`

I think you will also need [subscript / superscript letters](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_sup) in your html.

Now you have the links on how to do it. Do  a bit of research. I wish you luck.

Comment: The problem I faced with the subscript / superscript numbers in html isn't that my code can't take it, but that it is harder for the user to enter it.